# DataTemplate load ToolTip by MouseEnter

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a window where the user can select a directory and then all files in this directory are displayed in a listBox. Each file is displayed with a checkbox and the filename.

Now I want to show a tooltip if the file is a "know" image file. What I got so far, is that all tooltips are loaded if I select the path. This works fine. But there I have the problem, that the application becomes very slow if there are many images in a directory.

My current code for the listbox in the view looks like:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DirectoryItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=FilePath, Converter={StaticResource directoryItemConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Converter={StaticResource directoryItemToolTipConverter}}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Upload, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

DirectoryItems is an ObservableCollection of type UploadFile.

The Upload-File class is:

```
 class UploadFile
    {
        public UploadFile(string filePath)
        {
            this.FilePath = filePath;
            this.Upload = false;
        }

        public string FilePath { get; private set; }
        public bool Upload { get; set; }
    }
```

The DirectoryItemToolTipConverter, which is used in the view looks like:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    UploadFile uploadFile = (UploadFile)value;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(uploadFile.FilePath);
    if (extension != null && knownImageExtension.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(uploadFile.FilePath), previewImageSize, previewImageSize);
        Image image = new Image
        {
            Source = ImageToImageSourceConverter.ConvertBitmap(bitmap),
            Width = previewImageSize,
            Height = previewImageSize
        };
        return image;
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I achieve that the tooltips are loaded at the moment, the mouse enters the checkbox the first time? Is there an "easy" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=FilePath, Converter={StaticResource directoryItemConverter}}"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          IsChecked="{Binding Upload, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <CheckBox.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="ToolTip">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource directoryItemToolTipConverter}}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </CheckBox.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```